# PLS-00049: bad bind variable (1)

Tags: sql, oracle, compiler-errors

Someone could help me to find my error ?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER  Assign_Prix
    BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE 
    ON DetailCommande
    FOR EACH ROW

    DECLARE
        v_NOECHELLE Integer; v_PRIX Integer;

    BEGIN

    SELECT NOECHELLE INTO v_NOECHELLE
    FROM ECHELLE
    WHERE ddebut<=:new.ddebut AND dfin>=:new.dfin;

    SELECT Min(Prix) INTO v_Prix
    FROM DETAILECHELLE
    WHERE noechelle = v_Echelle AND qtemin<=:new.qtemin;

   :NEW.PRIX:= v_Prix;

END;


CREATE TABLE Echelle 
    ( 
     NoEchelle NUMBER  NOT NULL,
     CodeProduit VARCHAR2 (15)  NOT NULL ,
     DDebut DATE NOT NULL,
     DFin DATE NOT NULL
    ) 
;
ALTER TABLE Echelle 
    ADD CONSTRAINT Echelle_PK PRIMARY KEY ( NoEchelle ) ;
ALTER TABLE Echelle
    ADD CONSTRAINT Echelle_FK_Produit FOREIGN KEY (CodeProduit)
        REFERENCES Produit(CodeProduit);


CREATE TABLE DetailEchelle
    (
     NoEchelle NUMBER NOT NULL ,
     NoDetail NUMBER NOT NULL ,
     QteMin NUMBER  NOT NULL , 
     Prix NUMBER  NOT NULL 
     )
;
ALTER TABLE DetailEchelle
    ADD CONSTRAINT DetailEchelle_PK PRIMARY KEY ( NoEchelle, NoDetail);
ALTER TABLE DetailEchelle
    ADD CONSTRAINT DetailEchelle_FK_Echelle FOREIGN KEY (NoEchelle)
        REFERENCES Echelle(NoEchelle);

CREATE TABLE Produit 
    ( 
     CodeProduit VARCHAR2 (15)  NOT NULL , 
     CodeCategorie VARCHAR2 (5)  NOT NULL ,
     Nom VARCHAR2 (30)  NOT NULL , 
     Description VARCHAR2 (100) , 
     CoutFixe NUMBER , 
     LimiteSupCF NUMBER , 
     Delai NUMBER  
    ) 
;
ALTER TABLE Produit 
    ADD CONSTRAINT Produit_PK PRIMARY KEY ( CodeProduit ) ;
ALTER TABLE Produit
    ADD CONSTRAINT Produit_FK_Categorie FOREIGN KEY (CodeCategorie)
        REFERENCES Categorie(CodeCategorie);

CREATE TABLE DetailCommande 
    ( 
     NoCommande NUMBER  NOT NULL , 
     LigneCommande NUMBER  NOT NULL ,
     Qte NUMBER  NOT NULL ,  
     Message VARCHAR2 (100) NOT NULL,
     CodeProduit VARCHAR2 (15)  NOT NULL , 
     CodeCouleur VARCHAR2 (4)  NOT NULL , 
     PrixUnitVendu NUMBER, 
     CFVendu NUMBER
    ) 
;
ALTER TABLE DetailCommande 
    ADD CONSTRAINT DetailCommande_PK PRIMARY KEY ( LigneCommande, NoCommande ) ;
ALTER TABLE DetailCommande
    ADD CONSTRAINT DetailCommande_FK_Commande FOREIGN KEY (NoCommande)
        REFERENCES Commande(NoCommande);
ALTER TABLE DetailCommande
    ADD CONSTRAINT DetailCommande_FK_Produit FOREIGN KEY (CodeProduit, CodeCouleur)
        REFERENCES ProduitCouleur(CodeProduit, CodeCouleur);
```

Comment: What line is the error on?  What are the definitions of the three tables involved in this trigger?

Comment: Erreur(8,21): PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'NEW.DDEBUT'
Erreur(8,43): PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'NEW.DFIN'
Erreur(12,47): PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'NEW.QTEMIN'
Erreur(14,7): PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'NEW.PRIX'

Comment: OK.  What are the definitions of the three tables in question?  Does the `DetilCommande` table actually have all the columns you're trying to reference from the `:new` pseudorecord?

Comment: After verification ... YES. Does ':new.prix' (last line) has to refer to a specific Table ?

Comment: What are the definitions of the three tables?  Yes, `:new.prix` would need to refer to the `prix` column in the row that you're currently inserting into the `DetailCommande` table.  If there is no `prix` column in that table, you'd get the error you're encountering.  That's why I've asked for the definitions of the tables three times.

Comment: Your trigger is on the `DetailCommande` table.  You haven't posted the definition of that table.

Answer (score 1):

Your trigger is defined on the `DetailCommande` table.  This table does not have a column named `ddebut`, `dfin`, `qtemin` or `prix`.  Your trigger, therefore, cannot reference those columns in the `:new` pseudo-record since they don't exist in the table.

Unfortunately, if those columns don't exist in the `DetailCommande` table, I'm hard-pressed to guess at what your trigger is supposed to do so I have no idea what the proper syntax would be.

Comment: Thanks. That's very clear !

I changed the trigger Detailcommande for Commande. All my :new pseudo-record are defined in this table. Result : trigger compiled.